# Where can I find the appendix of FIXimate?

Tags: fix-protocol

I am reading on this site
http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/latestEP/en/FIX.5.0SP2_EP194/tag448.html

and there mentioned

"See Appendix 6-G - Use of  Component Block"

But I can't find the appendix anywhere on the fixtradingcommunity homepage or the FIXimate..?!

Maybe you know where to find it!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on page 470 of the file *FIX 5.0 Service Pack 2 with 20110818 Errata Specification - Volume 6*, which you can find on the [specs page for FIX 5.0 SP2](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/pg/structure/tech-specs/fix-version/50-service-pack-2). You need to be registered (registration is free) and logged in to be able to view specifications.

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer is what you were looking for, could you please accept it?

Comment: And why not register while you're at it, so you don't look like a noob?  You've been here long enough.